What is the origin (country and era) of this shell casing?
The letters written on it are as follows: 1/936, 75/27, ANS and there is what looks like a G and a B intertwined.

"how to attach photos": when you post/edit, there's an icon (landscape) on the top bar. Click and browse :) please take a minute for the [tour] and read [ask]. Should be helpful.

Measurements would alread narrow it down significantly, too.

I will give you an educated guess:
"75/27": designations in this format normally refer to the caliber (75mm) and the barrel length in comparison (The barrel is 27 times the caliber).
While 75mm was a standard of the time and many armies had their own gun designs for it, there was only one gun who would fit this specific description, the aptly named Cannone da 75/27 modello 11, used by the Italians in WW1 and WW2.
An intertwined GB would be Breda (located in Giovanni), an Italian manufacturer who did produce weapons and ammo (among other things).
I have no idea what 1/936 and ANS mean, normally those are something like batch numbers or factory identifiers.

I never know whether to marvel or frown at such feats of crystal ball scrying, rewarding sub-standard questions with above-standard replies. +1, and a tip of the hat.
